# How do you delete/empty/clear an SQL Analysis Services Cube?

Tags: ssas

Ok, this is a noobie question, can't seem to find the answer in google.

As we know, the SSAS cube is stored in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data"

How do you empty an SQL Server Analysis Services Cube? I do not want to delete the entire cube, I just want to delete data in it.

Thanks

Comment: question does not make sense. You build a cube from a data source such as a warehouse. rebuild it. An empty cube means nothing

Comment: There is data in the cube right?

Comment: yes. but see previous comment. WHY do you think you need an empty cube?

Comment: His question makes sense for maintenance purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to delete all data of a cube, you **unprocess** it. The easiest way to do that is as follows:

- Either in Management Studio right-click the Analysis Services database, or in BIDS, right-click the project.
- Then select "Process",
- in the dialog that appears, change the selection from "Process Full" to "Unprocess",
- and finally, click OK.